# Quickblox iOS: chatRoomOccupantDidJoin method

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

`Quickblox iOS SDK` v2.3.0.1 Implementing new `QBChatDelegate` method:

```
- (void)chatRoomOccupantDidJoin:(NSUInteger)userId roomJID:(NSString *)roomJID
```

Receiving 0 as user ID.

What I have:

```
-(void)chatRoomOccupantDidJoin:(NSUInteger)userId roomJID:(NSString *)roomJID
{
    NSLog(@"USER JOINED: %tu", userId);
}
```

And what I get when other user join chat:

```
USER JOINED: 0
```

Same thing with `chatRoomOccupantDidLeave` method.

Am I doing something wrong or did I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

Vitaliy, please try to update your iOS version to the latest one - 2.3.0.4 to see it the issue persists.